# Dummy Network Driver

Tags: kernel-modules, network-interface

I have failed to come up with a dummy network driver through google search.i am planning to write a network driver in C that is linked to protocol stack but not linked to any hardware
The online tutorial has for `kernel Version 2.X` 
But I am `Kernel Version 3.13.0-24-generic`.Moreover I have noticed that the net_dev structure has changed.So its hard to map with the online tutorial.

Please provide me a reference of online tutorial.It will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Such a posibility exists:

```
sudo ip link add d1 type dummy
```

See the manual page for ip:

```
man ip
```

Comment: Sir I want to write a program for it.Not by command